# consult-man, consult-grep, etc. don't match anything

Tags: grep, consult

Emacs 29.0.60 running on Windows 10 with Msys2 and Git for Windows.

I'm trying out the `consult` package, particularly functions such as `consult-grep` and `consult-man`, and I'm finding that I apparently don't know how to use them. After starting emacs with `emacs -q`, I first execute

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(package-initialize)
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))
```

to tell emacs where to find packages. Then, in the scratch buffer, I execute

```
(require 'consult)
```

Now I do `M-x consult-grep` and in the minibuffer I get

```
Grep (Project .emacs.d): #
```

Typing anything, including `.*`, after `#` and hitting return results in

```
Grep (Project .emacs.d): #.* [No match]
```

The `grep` command emacs finds (if it's calling `grep` at all) is the one from Git for Windows,

```
(executable-find "grep")
"c:/Users/rdprice/Apps/Git/usr/bin/grep.exe"
```

`M-x grep` works just fine. Is there configuration that I'm missing, or does `consult` have trouble on Windows, or what?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Have you also tried `consult-ripgrep` (it require to have `ripgrep` installed on your system). It works perfectly on my system (much better than `grep` / `consult-grep`. But I'm on GNU/LInux Arch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config which works well on my system (GNU Linux Arch, Emacs 28.2). `use-package` is installed by default on Emacs 29 (below 29 you have to install `use-package` manually). It should work on Windows if `grep` or `ripgrep` are installed properly (I remember it working on my Windows 10).

### Package Management

#### Emacs Package Repositories

```el
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives
   '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
     ("elp" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("gnu-devel" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/")
     ("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/")
     ))
```

#### Package config tool (`use-package`)

##### Package installation

- Auto install all packages called by `use-package`

```el
(require 'use-package-ensure)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
```

##### Package update

- Keep packages called by `use-package` automatically updated

```el
(use-package auto-package-update
  :config
  (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t)
  (setq auto-package-update-hide-results t)
  (auto-package-update-maybe))
```

### Search

#### `consult`

```el
(use-package consult
  :init
  (define-prefix-command 'Consult)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'Consult)
  :bind
  ("C-f" . consult-line)
  ("C-c s f" . consult-find)
  ("C-c s g" . consult-grep)
  ("C-c s l" . consult-line)
  ("C-c s L" . consult-line-multi)
  ("C-c s k" . consult-keep-lines)
  ("C-c s r" . consult-ripgrep)
  ("C-c s u" . consult-focus-lines)
  :config
  (setq consult-narrow-key "<"))
```

Note: the search is performed on the directory (and sub-directories) where the buffer from where you launch the command is located.

Comment: My init.el file already uses `use-package`, although I don't update automatically as you do. I prefer to do it manually. I just did that through `package-list-packages`. No difference; I still see the same behavior. I posted the results from `emacs -q` to ensure that no other packages were messing things up.

Comment: I just tried `consult-git-grep`, which works. Go figure.

Comment: I just installed `ripgrep`; turns out `consult-ripgrep` works, too. But... `consult-man`, `consult-find`, and `consult-locate` all exhibit the same broken behavior.

Comment: Probably not related to emacs or consult, but to how Windows handles GNU  CLIs (like `find`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in competing executables in Git for Windows, MSYS2, and MinGW. I followed this advice from [help-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2022-02/msg00228.html) to remove all MSYS2 executables from PATH and `exec-path`. An except from the post:

> Completely segregate MSYS2 from the native Windows applications. Don't add the MSYS2 bin directory to your system-wide Path, and have Path only reference directories with native Windows and MinGW executables.

> If you need some Unix application to be callable from Emacs, always try to find a native Windows port of it; do NOT be tempted to install an MSYS2 port.  (Note that the MSYS2 project distributes both MSYS2 ports and MinGW64 ports, so you need to be aware of what you install.  Unfortunately, some packages exist only as MSYS2 apps, because no one ported them to MinGW.)

Now `consult-grep` works as advertised. Unfortunately, however, MinGW does not provide `man`, `find`, or `locate`; those executables exist only in MSYS2.

One other fix was required: The complete path to the Git for Windows executable has to be specified, as follows

```
(defvar my-git-dir "C:\\Users\\rdprice\\Apps\\Git\\bin")
(defvar my-git-executable (expand-file-name "git.exe" my-git-dir))
(setq vc-git-program my-git-executable)
```

Including a path to `git` in `exec-path` would pick up other MSYS2 or Git For Windows executables, so all you can do is just point emacs directly to `git.exe`.

Comment: Try [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).